# Dockerfile Automated Build from Github- Tag not found

Tags: github, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am new to Docker and am trying to set up an automatic build of my Github Repo:

https://github.com/satishsa1107/perl_helloworld

I added a Dockerfile with the following code:

```
FROM satishsa1107/perl_helloworld:latest
CMD perl hello.pl
```

My DockerHub is setup here:

docker.io/satishsa1107/perl_helloworld

When I try to build it, I get the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 58.37 kB Sending build context to Docker daemon 58.37 kB
Step 1 : FROM satishsa1107/perl_helloworld:latest
Pulling repository docker.io/satishsa1107/perl_helloworld
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/satishsa1107/perl_helloworld
ERROR: Build process returned exit code 1
ERROR: Build in 'master' (ef8abd92) failed in 0:00:16
```

I don't get it because when I set up my build settings in DockerHub, I added the following settings:

```
Type     Name       Dockerfile Location    Docker Tag Name
branch   master     /                      latest
```

I assumed this meant that it was tagging my master branch in my Github Repo as latest, and I could refer to it as satishsa1107/perl_helloworld:latest but doesn't seem to be working.

Also, in DockerHub I see tags as empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FROM` statement is always the base image you want to use to compile your own image, so in this case Docker is looking for the image docker.io/satishsa1107/perl_helloworld:latest in order to compile your image, so it won't work.

I recommend you to read more about the Dockerfile here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

A possible option for your `FROM` command is to reference the standard Perl as stated here: https://hub.docker.com/_/perl/

The Dockerfile would look like:

```
FROM perl:5.20
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "perl", "./hello.pl" ]
```

Comment: I created this example project just to test Docker so maybe it isn't a good example. I guess my main question is regarding "latest" tag not being linked to my master branch.

Comment: @noobuntu there is no real link between your Docker tag and your GIT branch, this configuration on Docker HUB means that whenever you push something into your master branch docker will pull it and build a new docker image (based on your Dockerfile and automatically push it onto the Docker tag latest). 

In summary, your code on GIT master will trigger the build of the Docker latest image.